# How should I correct this unstability of the PDEs results?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I try to solve PDE as the following code but it seems to have an error. I[image: error]
How should I correct this?

Thank you

```
 sol = c[x, t] /. 
   NDSolve[{D[c[x, t], 
       t] == (0.025806686)*D[c[x, t], x, x] - (0.264)*
        D[c[x, t], 
         x] - (1600/0.56)*(2.37*0.01027/(1 + 0.01027*c[x, t])^2)*
        D[c[x, t], t], c[x, 0] == 0, c[0, t] == 1}, 
    c, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 500}];
Plot3D[sol, {x, 0, 40}, {t, 0, 4000}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 97, MaxRecursion -> 7, Mesh -> 19, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, t, z}, 
   ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[z, {-1, 1}]]], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{{White, White, Yellow, Orange, Red}, {0, 1}}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Bed Depth (cm)", "Time (min)", "C/Co"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.80]]
```

Comment: You could start by changing your setup to eliminating the messages.

Comment: When I paste your code into Mathematica it gives me two error messages. First it says the boundary conditions are inconsistent. Your code says the value is zero along the t==0 border, but is 1 along the x==0 border. What happens when x==0 and t==0? Next is says two conditions are insufficient for an equation with first and second order derivatives. Can you correct both of those?